# Expectation and variance of quotient of sums of positive, discrete, iid random variables

Tags: variance, random-variable, expected-value

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be $n$ positive, discrete (so positive integers) and IID random variables. Let $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be constants and
$$Y=\frac{\sum c_iX_i}{\big(\sum X_i\big)^2}\ \ \ ;\ \ \ Z=\frac{1}{\sum X_i}$$

I'm trying to calculate $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\text{var}(Y)$ in terms of $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$'s. Similarly for expectation and variance of $Z$. I've looked at other answers related to calculating the expectation of inverses and quotients, but they deal with more general cases and involve integrals and all.

Given the assumptions about $X_i$'s that I listed out, how can $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\text{var}(Y)$ be calculated?

Comment: Check this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302436/expectation-of-inverse-of-sum-of-random-variables

Comment: @Ale: I already did, but that one involves integration, which I don't think is needed for my case. And the second answer there provides a lower bound. There must be a simpler way to compute expectation and variance of $Y$?

Comment: There is no universal formula that improves on the definitions.  For instance, to find $E[Z]$ first find the distribution of $X=\sum X_i.$ Then, by definition, $E[Z] = \sum_{x} \Pr(X=x)/x.$ If you are hoping for anything simpler, then you will need to be more specific about the distribution of the $X_i.$

Comment: @whuber: completely fair, but what you listed as the formula for $E[Z]$ is for case when it's a function of only one RV, i.e. $X$. What about the case when it's a function of multiple RV's $X_1,\ldots,X_n$? As for the distribution, assume that we can calculate, for any $X_i$, the probability $P(X_i=k)$, where $k$ is a positive integer. $X_i$'s don't have a standard probability distribution like uniform or normal though.

Comment: That's such a general situation there's nothing to add.  I hope the generalization from a univariate discrete variable to a multivariate discrete variable is obvious: a single sum becomes a sum over $N$ variables, that's all.

Comment: @whuber: Sorry but not obvious to me, especially if I want to come up with an expression for expectation of $Y$, I'm new to this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's literally the definition: you sum all values times their probabilities.

Comment: @whuber: So then $E[g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]=\sum_{x_1}\ldots\sum_{x_n}P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$? And I can break up the probability $P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)$ into products involving $P(X_i=x_i)$. Is that correct?

Comment: The former part is the definition of expectation.  The "breaking up" part is the definition of *independent.*

Comment: I suppose for $Z$ you might be able to find a confidence set using Fieller's Method or the approach by von Luxburg and Franz -- if $E(\sum X_i)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll get a tractable expression in terms of $E(X_i)$. If you have a concrete expression for $P(X_j=n)$, and denote $S_j\equiv X_j/(\sum X_i)^2$, then in this case you can calculate:
$$
\begin{align}
E(S_j)&=\sum_{a_1,\ldots,a_n}P(X_1=a_1, \ldots,X_n=a_n)\frac{a_j}{(\sum_ia_i)^2}
\\&=\sum_{a_1,\ldots,a_n}P(X_1=a_1)\ldots P(X_n=a_n)\frac{a_j}{(\sum_ia_i)^2}
\end{align}
$$
where the second equality follows from independence of $X_i$. In addition, since $X_i$ are identically distributed, so are $S_i$, which means the above expression holds for all $j=1,\ldots,n$. Finally, note that $Y=\sum_j c_jS_j$, so by linearity of expectation, $$E(Y)=\sum_jc_jE(S_j)=\mu_S\sum_jc_j$$ since all $E(S_j)$ are the same and we denote the common value by $\mu_S$.

Similarly you can calculate $E(Z)$. To get the variance, you can calculate $E(Y^2)$ and the variance calculation follows.

Comment: Since the $X_i$ are assumed *iid,* your formula is unnecessarily cumbersome: it will suffice to compute the expectation of $X_1/\sum_i(X_i^2).$ Even that is potentially amenable to simplification, because it can be expressed in terms of the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2^2 + \cdots X_n^2.$

Comment: @whuber: Ah yes you're correct! I forgot about the _identically distributed_ part. I've at least partially simplified it.

Comment: @whuber How are you getting $E[X_1/(\sum_i X_i)^2] = E[X_1/\sum_i X_i^2]$?